# How to Stream Videos Using AWS Media Convert Programmatically

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3, aws-media-convert

Hope you all are fine. I Want your help
How do i build Video Stream App in Dot Net Core Using AWS Media Services like AWS Media Convert. I have a video which is already uploaded to the s3 bucket. Now I want to stream video using aws media services not from IFromFile only.
Is there any way you people suggest?

Answer (score 0):

**How to use AWS MediaConvert for broadcasting videos efficiently like YouTube**

1. Go to Creating an AWS MediaConvert **Job**
2. Set an **input S3 bucket**
3. Select Output as **Apple HLS**
   [image: Step 3 - Select Output as Apple HLS]
4. Set an **output S3 Bucket** preferably separate from input S3 bucket
5. Select **Automated ABR**
   [image: Step 5 and 6]
6. Set **Min ABR bitrate (bits/s)** to be 100000
7. Click **Create**